# EOFError while parsing .netrc in CI job for accessing GitLab PyPI package registry

Tags: python, gitlab, continuous-integration, .netrc

I have a CI job in repo **A** that builds an image (`Dockerfile` via Kaniko), which requires a package from a package repository from repo **B**.

Since this is a task that will repeat in the future quite a bit, I created a GAT (group access token, rights: **api**, role: **Developer**) called `CI_GROUP_API` with a corresponding group CICD variable with the same name and value, so that my CI job can access all other repos in that group by using it.

I use the GAT to generate a `.netrc` on-the-fly in my CI job and I'm also adjusting my `requirements.txt` to add the package (will make this change permanent in the future). The files that are required for the CI job can be seen after the error log below. When I run my job I receive:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (24.0)
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Looking in indexes: https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/58838/packages/pypi/simple
User for gitlab.company.com: ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 44, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 297, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 890, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 831, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/sources.py", line 194, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 791, in process_project_url
    index_response = self._link_collector.fetch_response(project_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 461, in fetch_response
    return _get_index_content(location, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 364, in _get_index_content
    resp = _get_simple_response(url, session=session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 135, in _get_simple_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 520, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 710, in send
    r = dispatch_hook("response", hooks, r, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/hooks.py", line 30, in dispatch_hook
    _hook_data = hook(hook_data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 500, in handle_401
    username, password, save = self._prompt_for_password(parsed.netloc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/auth.py", line 455, in _prompt_for_password
    username = ask_input(f"User for {netloc}: ") if self.prompting else None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 251, in ask_input
    return input(message)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 2
```

---

My CI job is defined as follows:

```
build-service:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: ['']
  tags:
    - asprunner
  rules:
    # Build base image only if the Dockerfile or CICD config file have changed and been pushed to the cloud branch
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "dev"'
      when: on_success
  script:
    - echo "Building image for service X using Kaniko"
    - |
      export BASE_REGISTRY_URL=registry.gitlab.company.com/mygroup/base-service
      export BASE_TOKEN_NAME=CI_GROUP_API
      export BASE_TOKEN_VALUE=$CI_GROUP_API

      cat <<EOT >> .netrc
      machine gitlab.company.com
      login $BASE_TOKEN_NAME
      password $BASE_TOKEN_VALUE
      EOT

      cat <<EOT >> requirements.txt
      --index-url https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/58838/packages/pypi/simple
      base-service
      
      EOT

      echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"},\"${BASE_REGISTRY_URL}\":{\"username\":\"${BASE_TOKEN_NAME}\",\"password\":\"${BASE_TOKEN_VALUE}\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor
       --context .
       --dockerfile Dockerfile
       --insecure
       --skip-tls-verify
       --skip-tls-verify-pull
       --insecure-pull
       --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:v0.2"
```

My corresponding `Dockerfile` can be seen below:

```
FROM registry.company.com/mygroup/base-service:v1.0
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY ./.netrc .netrc
RUN echo "----------- requirements.txt -----------" && cat requirements.txt 
RUN echo "----------- .netrc -----------" && cat .netrc
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip && pip3 install --no-cache -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir -p service
COPY main.py service/
COPY gltf_transformer service/

RUN rm requirements.txt .netrc

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "python3 main.py"]
```

The resulting `pip`-related files look like this:

**requirements.txt**

```
pygltflib
--index-url https://gitlab.company.com/api/v4/projects/58838/packages/pypi/simple
x-base-service
```

**.netrc**

----------- .netrc -----------

```
machine gitlab.company.com
login CI_GROUP_API
password [MASKED]
```

I thought that perhaps the `[MASKED]`, which is how GitLab hides masked variables in the CI job's logs, might have been written to the `.netrc` as the actual value. However, first the error comes while reading the user and second I added

artifacts:
paths:
- requirements.txt
- .netrc
when: on_failure

to my job to get the files and verified that the token's value is there.

I have also downloaded both files locally to my system and ran pip for the `requirements.txt` using the `.netrc` from the job's artifacts. It worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very, very inaccurate.

First I need to clarify that the only reason it worked locally was because `pip` was using my SSH to connect to the package repository and `.netrc` was actually never used. I found that out when I ran the `pip` with the `requirements.txt` file in a clean environment and it asked me for used name and password.

My next thought was that it's the encoding that's the problem. After all the documentation states:

[[image: .netrc documentation on non-ASCII characters1]

However, using `iconv` for converting the UTF-8 to ASCII didn't do anything and the error was still there.

Then I remembered, while reading the documentation for the Nth time, that the `.netrc` is related to a specific user. Now, inside a Docker container we don't really have users, however we do have the `/root` directory as the home directory.

I added

```
COPY ./.netrc /root/.netrc
```

to my Dockerfile, followed by fixing all following paths referring to the file and it worked.

The `man-pages` for `.netrc` do state:

[image]

So `NETRC` environment variable can also be used if a specific location other than the user's home directory is required.